# Trying to convert ISO 8601 duration format to add to date in bash

Tags: bash, date, sed

Sorry this may seem really specific, but it comes down to a sed problem I can't figure out.

Context:
I'm trying to write a bash function that takes in an arbitrary ISO 8601 format duration (e.g. `P1DPT12M1S`, `P15MPT12M40S`, etc.) and converts it into a string that I can use to add to a date via something like: `date -d "$(date) + 1 day + 1 minute"`

This is what I have so far:

```sh
duration_parser() {\
    duration=$1\
    duration=$(sed 's/PT\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)S/PT\1 + \2 second/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/PT\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)M/PT\1 + \2 minute/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/PT\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)H/PT\1 + \2 hour/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/PT//g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/P\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)D/P\1 + \2 day/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/P\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)W/P\1 + \2 week/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/P\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)M/P\1 + \2 month/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/P\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)Y/P\1 + \2 year/g' <<< $duration)
    duration=$(sed 's/P//g' <<< $duration)
    echo $duration
}\

date -d "$(date) $(duration_parser PT6M3S)"
```

Which works for durations where each unit is one digit, e.g.

`date -d "$(date) $(duration_parser PT6M3S)"`

works, but when the units are multiple digits such as 60 minutes:

`date -d "$(date) $(duration_parser PT60M3S)"`

it does not. I can't seem to get sed to pick up all the digits...

Is there a way to do this with sed, or is this myabe not the best way to do this and there is an easier way? haha

Comment: All your `s/PT\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\)H/PT\1 + \2 hour/g` should look like `s/PT\(.*[^[:digit:]]\)\{1,0\}\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)H/PT\1 + \2 hour/g`: replace `\(.*\)` with `\(.*[^[:digit:]]\)\{1,0\}` and `\([[:digit:]]\)` with `\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)`

Comment: AND I think you can avoid so many calls to `sed`. Chain your cmds together like `duration=$(sed 's/../.hour/g;s/../.hour/g;s/../...hour/g' <<< $duration)`. Technically there is not reason not to chain them all together, but there may be something about your logic that prevents that. Good luck.

Comment: You should set `LC_ALL=C` or `TZ` to something before calling `date`, the `+ 1 month + 1 year etc.` may not be parsed correctly on different locales. ISO8601 also allows floats, ex. `P0.5Y` specifies half of one year.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey sorry went out for lunch haha. wow thanks for the super speedy reply! So I tried using your recommendation and I'm getting a bash error : 

`sed: -e expression #1, char 70: Invalid content of \{\}`

I'm not gonna lie, I have no idea what \{\} does in sed lol. What is the change doing, if you don't mind me asking. Still trying to learn how to bash lol

Comment: @shellter thanks for the suggestion! Still trying to get it to work before cleaning up this nasty code lol

Comment: @KamilCuk ^same

Comment: try using `sed -E 's/../.../'` for Wiktor's improvements. Good luck.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/IVfV9z, it seems to work.

Comment: I'm actually getting closer thanks to your guys' comments! 
This works: `duration=$(sed 's/\(PT.*[^[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]]*\)S/\1 + \2 second/g' <<< $duration)` up to the the first unit. So PT30M30S becomes PT30M + 30 second. Is there a way I can get sed to have .* match when it is blank (e.g. in the case PT30M, there is no text between PT and 30). Thanks a lot again guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` has it's own language, where you can chain commands, even handle errors.

I ended with this:

```
dur_to_dateadd() {
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations
    # PnYnMnDTnHnMnS <- we handle only this
    <<<"$1" sed -E '
        # it has to start with p
        /^P/!{
            s/.*/ERROR: Invalid input - it has to start with P: "&"/
            q1
        }
        s/^P//

        # add an unredable 0x01 on the end
        # it serves as our "line separator"
        s/$/\x01/

        # parse from the beginning, add to the end after \x01
        s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)Y(.*)/\3 + \1 year/
        s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)M(.*)/\3 + \1 month/
        s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)D(.*)/\3 + \1 day/
        /^T/{
            s///
            s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)H(.*)/\3 + \1 hour/
            s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)M(.*)/\3 + \1 minute/
            s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)S(.*)/\3 + \1 second/
        }

        # we should have parsed it all
        # so our separator \x01 has to be the first character
        /^\x01/!{
          # there is something unparsed in the input
            s/\x01.*//
            s/.*/ERROR: Unparsable input: "&"/
            q1
        }
        # remove the \x01
        s///

        # just convert , to . in case of floats
        s/,/./g
    '
}

dur_to_dateadd "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S"
dur_to_dateadd "P23DT23H"
dur_to_dateadd "P4Y"
dur_to_dateadd "PT0S"
dur_to_dateadd "P0D"
dur_to_dateadd "P1M"
dur_to_dateadd "PT1M"
dur_to_dateadd "P0,5Y"
dur_to_dateadd "P0.5Y"
dur_to_dateadd "PT36H"
dur_to_dateadd "P1DT12H"
dur_to_dateadd "invalid" || echo error
dur_to_dateadd "P1Dinvalid" || echo error
dur_to_dateadd "PinvalidDT" || echo error
```

which outputs:

```
 + 3 year + 6 month + 4 day + 12 hour + 30 minute + 5 second
 + 23 day + 23 hour
 + 4 year
 + 0 second
 + 0 day
 + 1 month
 + 1 minute
 + 0.5 year
 + 0.5 year
 + 36 hour
 + 1 day + 12 hour
ERROR: Invalid input - it has to start with P: "invalid"
error
ERROR: Unparsable input: "invalid"
error
ERROR: Unparsable input: "invalidDT"
error
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/CavernousMassiveBytecode).

Short description: First I remove the initial `^P` and I append an unreadable character `\x01` on the end of the input. It serves as a "line separator" that separates unparsed input from parsed input/output string. Then we parse input from the beginning - we handle `^<number>Y`, then `^<number>M` and so on. If for example `^<number>Y` is matched, then we add `+ \1 year` on the end of the string after `\x01` and anything else. Parsed parts are removed as we parse them. Then comes a little error checking - if everything from the input is parsed, the `\x01` should be the first character in pattern space. If it is, we remove it and end - print the pattern space.

Just for fun, below I also added support to handle `PnW` `PYYYYMMDDThhmmss` and `PYYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` formats, they are easy to parse, you can match everything with a single match.

```
dur_to_dateadd() {
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations
    # We support formats:
    # PnYnMnDTnHnMnS
    # PnW
    # PYYYYMMDDThhmmss 
    # PYYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
    <<<"$1" sed -E '
        # it has to start with p
        /^P/!{
            s/.*/ERROR: Invalid input - it has to start with P: "&"/
            q1
        }
        s///

        # add an unredable 0x01 on the end
        # it serves as our "line separator"
        s/$/\x01/

        # handle PnW format
        /^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)W(.*)/{
            s//\3 + \1 week/
            b finish
        }

        # handle PYYYYMMDDThhmmss format
        /^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.*)/{
            s//\7 + \1 year + \2 month + \3 day + \4 hour + \5 minute + \6 second/
            b finish
        }

        # handle PYYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format
        /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(.*)/{
            s//\7 + \1 year + \2 month + \3 day + \4 hour + \5 minute + \6 second/
            b finish
        }


        # PnYnMnDTnHnMnS format
        # parse from the beginning, add to the end after \x01
        s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)Y(.*)/\3 + \1 year/
        s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)M(.*)/\3 + \1 month/
        s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)D(.*)/\3 + \1 day/
        /^T/{
            s///
            s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)H(.*)/\3 + \1 hour/
            s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)M(.*)/\3 + \1 minute/
            s/^([0-9]*([,.][0-9]*)?)S(.*)/\3 + \1 second/
        }

        : finish

        # we should have parsed it all
        # so our separator \x01 has to be the first cahracter
        /^\x01/!{
          # there is something unparsed in the input
            s/\x01.*//
            s/.*/ERROR: Unparsable input: "&"/
            q1
        }
        # remove the \x01
        s///

        # just convert , to . in case of floats
        s/,/./g
    '
}
```

Comment: Welp that works, but there's no way in hell I'm figuring out what that does for a bit LOL. Gonna have to stare at it for a while, but you my friend, are the true bash god.

Comment: Thank you so much again :))

Comment: Beautiful `sed` code, who what have thunk it ;-!? Good luck to all.

Comment: @jchen0022 : If you really want/need to understand this, the [Sed Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) will get up to speed. Take your time to run each of the examples there, experiment with them (make small changes) so you can develope your understanding. Cheers.